# Wordpress Date Splitting - Extra comma and Short Month

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am using the following code to split WordPress date into 3 lines. I am getting an extra comma after the date.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Secondly I want this month to be short like 'Sep' or 'Oct' or 'Nov' and so on. Just the first 3 letters.

**My Code**

```
<span class="post-date-day">
        <?php $data = explode(' ', get_the_date()); echo trim($data[1] .'</span>').'
        <span class="post-date-month">'.$data[0] .'</span>
        <span class="post-date-year">'.$data[2]; ?></span>
```

**My questions**

1. How can I get rid of that comma after 17 date in the screenshot?
2. How can I shorten the Month like 'Sep' or 'Oct' or 'Nov' and so on. Just the first 3 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exploding the date and then fixing it.

You should use the format option on the function [get_the_date( [string $format], [int $post_id] );](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date)

```
<span class="post-date-day"><?= get_the_date('j') ?></span>
<span class="post-date-month"><?= get_the_date('M') ?></span>
<span class="post-date-year"><?= get_the_date('Y') ?></span>
```

PHP date formats can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).